# black backgrounds appear grey on gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, colors, gnome-terminal

Running gnome under Ubuntu Lucid

```
$ env | grep TERM
TERM=xterm
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
```

I had to edit both my .muttrc and my vim colorscheme to change the background color from `black` to `none` in order to get a proper black background (or, more accurately, to retain the terminal's default black background). Setting it to `black` resulted in a dark grey background. This only happens with gnome-terminal; konsole, xterm and rxvt are fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I'm now using GNOME Terminal 2.32.0 and it still has the same problem. I fixed it by changing the color pallete. From the Edit menu, select Profile Preferences, then the Colors tab. Click on the upper left rectangle in the Color pallete, Palette entry 1. This has a default Color name of #2E3436. Change this to #000000. Voila!

Comment: Great, thanks - I've been battling between the server dishing out bad colours or vim setting them wrong, or setting the wrong terminal type! This is the real problem - the default 'black' for Gnome terminal is actually grey!

Comment: Thank you!  This was driving me nuts.  Can't believe this is still relevant 10 years later.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug.
A fix was released for Maverick in gnome-terminal 2.30.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/549552

Comment: I'm running gnome-terminal 2.30.2 and the bug, or at least the same symptoms, are still there.

Comment: still there in gnome-terminal 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Transparent Background set to non-maximum under Edit > Profile Preferences > Background?

Comment: no, i have my background set to solid black. the terminal itself is fine; it's only when i start vim up with a colorscheme that uses ctermbg="black" that the background changes to grey. in other words, it's interpreting the color setting "black" as a dark grey color. i checked the palette too, but that seemed fine.